# Strange isinstance behaviour in pandas int and np.int64

Tags: python, pandas, types

I have a series of `np.int64`, but for some reason using `isinstance()` in different cases yields different answers.

You can see in the attached image that if I check the type of the individual element, I get numpy.int64, and so the isinstance on this particular element works out correctly.

When I use apply, however, the opposite behavior happens, and I get different results. Is this because apply changes the type somehow?

In more detail, the original series is defined with:

`sample_series = pd.Series([np.int64(1), np.int64(25), np.int64(50) ,np.int64(75)])`

When I check the type of one element,`type(sample_series.loc[0])`, I get the output `numpy.int64`.

Now using isinstance gives me the following (expected) answers, `isinstance(sample_series.loc[0], int)` , with output: `False` and `isinstance(sample_series.loc[0], np.int64)` with output: `True`.

On the other hand, `sample_series.apply(lambda x : isinstance(x,int))` gives the output:

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool
```

While `sample_series.apply(lambda x : isinstance(x, np.int64))` gives the output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

So it seems that the results are inconsistent.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `DataFrame.apply` and `Series.apply` are slightly different under the hood. For instance:

```
sample_series = pd.Series([np.int64(1), np.int64(50), np.int64(75)])
#0     1
#1    50
#2    75
#dtype: int64

sample_series.apply(lambda x: type(x))
#0    <class 'int'>
#1    <class 'int'>
#2    <class 'int'>
#dtype: object
```

But

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': sample_series})
df.dtypes
#val    int64
#dtype: object

df.apply(lambda row: type(row.val), axis=1)
#0    <class 'numpy.int64'>
#1    <class 'numpy.int64'>
#2    <class 'numpy.int64'>
#dtype: object
```

If you look into the Series.apply code, it looks like the weird behavior comes about [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/series.py#L2546-L2551)

```
# row-wise access
if is_extension_type(self.dtype):
    mapped = self._values.map(f)
else:
    values = self.asobject
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
```

It's taking your series, and then creating `values` which is `array([1, 50, 75], dtype=object)` and passing that to another function in `pandas._libs` to apply your function `f = lambda x: isinstance(x, np.int64)`

On the other hand `DataFrame.apply` with `axis=1` works as expected, because when it defines `values` it does so by `values = self.values` [See here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L4944-L4951), which gives you `values = array([ 1, 50, 75], dtype=int64)`

In fact, if you were to change the underlying pandas Series.apply code to `values=self.values` you would get the output you would expect.

Answer (score -3):

It looks like passing `convert_dtype=False` to the `apply` call should solve your problem. Link to docs on this parameter:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply

As stated in the link above, the default of `True` will `Try to find better dtype for elementwise function results`, meaning that your `isinstance` calls in that lambda you are passing to `apply` are returning boolean values, and as such, the `apply` call is changing the data type of the contents of your `Series`.

Comment: Have you tested your answer? Testing is an important part of formulating a correct answer.

Comment: `convert_dtype=False` doesn't make any difference here. Tested with pandas 0.22.0 and Python 3.6.5

Comment: Fair enough, I will go crawl back in my hole instead of trying to be helpful. In the meantime, perhaps you could do something helpful @jpp? Or do you prefer to nitpick answers instead of making them.