# Why does isinstance return the wrong value only inside a series map?

Tags: python, pandas

A call to isinstance returns True outside but False inside a map over a series (and an applymap over a dataframe)...

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz
s = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp(2018,5,11,6,0,0,0, pytz.timezone('UTC'))])
s

0   2018-05-11 06:00:00+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

A call to isinstance for the single value in this series yields True.

```
isinstance(s.iloc[0], pd.Timestamp)
True
```

Inside a map over the series it gives True.

```
s.map(lambda x: isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp)).iloc[0]
True
```

But if we try something contingent on that value, say convert to a string...

```
s.map(lambda x: x.isoformat() if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) else x).iloc[0]
Timestamp('2018-05-11 06:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

...it appears to have returned False and the method isoformat is not called (The actual method call is irrelevant because its not called).

Comment: I'm not sure why you have this problem, but using `str(x)` and ensuring you always have `str` in your series seems to work: `s.map(lambda x: x.isoformat() if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) else str(x)).iloc[0]`.

Comment: There was a similar issue with `Series.apply` and `isinstance` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882785/strange-isinstance-behaviour-in-pandas-int-and-np-int64). Within `pandas.Series.map` the values are also set by `values = self.asobject` so perhaps they're related.

Comment: @jpp  I can work around it.  The actual use case is an applymap over a dataframe coercing Timestamps to strings so it can be saved to an xlsx file for excel.  Hence the need to return x if its not a timestamp.  The work around is to test for hasttr(x, 'isoformat').  I'm more interested in why it doesn't work because I really think it should.

Comment: @Ymareth, In that case you can use `df.applymap`, where I don't see the problem: `df.applymap(lambda x: x.isoformat() if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) else x).iloc[0]`.

Comment: `s.map(lambda x: x.isformat())` seems to cause `AttributionError`.  If you try `lambda x: 9 if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) else x` it returns `[9]` but `lambda x: x.isformat() if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) else x` returns `x`

Comment: @jpp But applymap (in a dataframe) has the same bug.  Like I said I can work around this issue my question is why does it happen.  The return values of isinstance outside and inside a map & applymap should not be different for the same argument.

Comment: @RonKalian Yes, typo - isoformat - will correct - but that doesn't change the problem.  It's not being called.

Comment: Why not `[x.isoformat() if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp)==True else x for x in s]
`

Comment: Yes @Wen `[x.isoformat() if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) else x for x in s]` seems to be a good workaround.  With `s.map...` it returns the wrong result for which I have no explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a00154dcfe5057cb3fd86653172e74b6893e337d/pandas/core/series.py#L2229-L2357) of `.map`, it appears that Pandas is checking if type of the Series is an [extension type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.api.types.is_extension_type.html). As OP points out, this will behave differently for different time zones. Let

```
s1 = pd.Series([
    pd.Timestamp(2018,5,11,6,0,0,0),
])

s2 = pd.Series([
    pd.Timestamp(2018,5,11,6,0,0,0, pytz.timezone('UTC')),
])
```

When `.map` is called, it checks `pd.api.types.is_extension_type(s)`. If `s == s1`, this returns `False`, while if `s == s2` this returns `True`.

As a result, `s2.map` turns into `s2._values.map`. Since `s2._values` is of type `DatetimeIndex`, the relevant implementation of `.map` is called. It first tries to call `f(s2._values)` and reverts to `s2._values.map(f)` if an error occurs.

In this case, `f = lambda x: x.isoformat(x) if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) else x`. No error occurs because `f` checks if `isinstance(s2._values, pd.Timestamp)`, which fails. Hence, `f(s2._values)` returns `s2._values`. Indeed, this can be verified with `s2._values is f(s2._values) == True`.

One workaround is to make sure that the `pd.api.types.is_extension_type` is not called, e.g. `s.astype(object).map`.

Comment: But isoformat is not being called so I'm not sure I agree.  I had thought it might be somekind of reverse conversion but as one of the commenters pointed out I spelt isoformat wrong (isformat) and there was no error - its not being called.  The lambda in the apply is just returning x.

Comment: @Ymareth after I changed the spelling and added a non-datetime object to the series, e.g. string `"cat"` you code performed as expected.

Comment: Yes, it's something specific to Timestamps and I noted Timestamps with timezones.  Doesn't seem to happen if the Timestamp is naive.

Comment: @Ymareth can you try running `lambda x: print(x.isoformat()) or x.isoformat() if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) else x`? I get the print statements on my machine, so the condition seems to work.

Comment: can you try... def f(x):
    print(x)
s.map(lambda x: f(x) if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) else x).iloc[0]  That doesn't print anything for me.

Comment: @Ymareth thanks for your comments; I think that you are right and no conversion occurs. I traced some steps through the source that hopefully show what is going on; not entirely sure as of why.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like datetime series are converted to DatetimeIndex and then the index passed to the function. Of course the index fails the `isinstance` check.

```
def f(x):
    print(x)
    if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp):
        print('{} == {}'.format(type(x).__name__, pd.Timestamp.__name__))
        return x.isoformat()
    else:
        print('{} != {}'.format(type(x).__name__, pd.Timestamp.__name__))
        return x

print(s.map(f))
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-05-11 06:00:00+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)
DatetimeIndex != Timestamp
0   2018-05-11 06:00:00+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

This does not happens with all series but it seems to depend on the type. Myabe it happens with extension types or only with datetime.